# objects experience THE SHAKE at great distance from center

Tags: game-engine

here is the problem in detail

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pyr5lWPqfkk&feature=youtu.be

does anyone know how to fix it? Or work around ?
i wanna create 1:1 scale space flight simulator so the bug is in the way.

Comment: Could you test it in UPBGE and, if it results the same, could you report the bug at [UPBGE's issues](https://github.com/UPBGE/blender/issues)? I don't think it's something related to a setting, I've heard about this bug before, it's something related to the floating point numbers precision.

Comment: the test video was actually done in UPBGE .  I know that it's floating point number precision problem but i wanna know how to workaround the problem . But how for example Kerbal Space Program doesn't encounter that problem in unity but in blender it's present

Comment: http://spaceexvr.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-i-got-around-floating-point.html someone fixed this in unity

Comment: Some workarounds I could think of:
 
- Decrease the scale of your universe, by re-scaling down all your assets or by decreasing the Unit Scale (Properties Editor > Scene > Units > Unit Scale).

- Move the player to center and the whole world by the resulting offset after some distance. Preety complicated, though... I see you opened the issue on UPBGE's repository, let's hope they come with a workaround (or even a fix).